# Problema con filtros en angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach, filtro

necesitaría saber que esta mal en este código ya que no logro visualizar los datos que quiero obtener, todo los demás esta bien, pero cuando quiero ver los datos con un console.log no se ven solo muestra [ ] vacíos.

lo que se obtiene es la cantidad de escuelas donde esta inscripto el docente, en console log dentro del if funcionaria bien, pero al estar fuera no arroja ningún dato.

Comment: Si se resolvió el problema, no deberías eliminar el código, porque la pregunta pierde sentido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos errores en tu código, el primero es que falta `return false;` cuando no se encuentra una coincidencia. El segundo, **y más importante**, es que no puedes detener la ejecución de `forEach()`, ni con `return` ni con `break`; según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> **Nota:** No hay forma de detener o cortar un bucle forEach que no sea lanzar una excepción**<sup>(1)</sup>**. Si necesita dicho comportamiento, el método .forEach() es la herramienta equivocada, use una simple iteración en su lugar. Si está probando los elementos del array para un predicado y necesita devolver un valor boleano, puede usar every() o some() en su lugar.

Usando [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) tu función quedaría:

```
const Filter = this._service.schools.filter(school=> {
    // Devuelve verdadero si this._users.usr.name se encuentra en school.name
    return school.name.some(name => name.id == this._users.usr.name);
}); 
console.log(Filter);
```

**<sup>(1)</sup>** Es muy mala idea usar excepciones para este propósito, simplemente rompería la "lógica natural" del script.